Why qiskit doesn't change the unitary representation of the CNOT gate when applied on the other direction
I am trying to work on a circuit simulator and was trying to get the unitary matrices from a circuit when I noticed that qiskit returns the same unitary no matter the configuration of the qubits.
Here is a sample code:
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit

# Create a Quantum Circuit with 2 qubits
qc = QuantumCircuit(2)

# Apply CNOT gate with control qubit 0 and target qubit 1
qc.cx(0, 1)
qc.cx(1, 0)

for instruction in qc.data:
    print(instruction.matrix, "\n")

# Draw the circuit
qc.draw('mpl')

which returns:
[[1.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j]
 [0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 1.+0.j]
 [0.+0.j 0.+0.j 1.+0.j 0.+0.j]
 [0.+0.j 1.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j]] 

[[1.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j]
 [0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 1.+0.j]
 [0.+0.j 0.+0.j 1.+0.j 0.+0.j]
 [0.+0.j 1.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j]] 

This seems odd to me as the second one should have a unitary matrix similar to the one shown in many textbook but instead is just the same as the first one.

Instruction.matrix might only refer to the internal matrix representation of the gate outside of any context ie it might not get changed when it is appended to a circuit. If this is true, going to a 3-qubit circuit shouldn't change the shape of these gates either.

What your code is doing under the hood is effectively equivalent to the following:
from qiskit.circuit.library import CXGate

CX_matrix = CXGate().to_matrix()
print(CX_matrix)

array([[1.+0.j, 0.+0.j, 0.+0.j, 0.+0.j],
       [0.+0.j, 0.+0.j, 0.+0.j, 1.+0.j],
       [0.+0.j, 0.+0.j, 1.+0.j, 0.+0.j],
       [0.+0.j, 1.+0.j, 0.+0.j, 0.+0.j]])

Notice how these lines of code are agnostic to the qubit ordering, so the matrix that will be displayed is what qiskit has internally defined for the CXGate().
